# Jquery function doesnt execute all commands

Tags: jquery, css

So I'm trying to make my own toggleable side bar using Jquery. my click function works on the side bar, however the main div won't budge.

```
$("#headerToggle").click( function() {
        $("#sidenav-toggle").toggleClass("sidenavToggle");
        
        $("#main").addClass("mainWide");
      });


#main{
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 190px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    }

.sidenav{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    width: 190px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.sidenavToggle{
    left: -190px;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.mainWide{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

This is my Jquery and CSS, I tried addclass and toggleClass on `#main` but it doesnt work . However, this works.

```
$("#main").css("margin-left","0px");
```

so I can atleast assure that the function calls out `#main` on click because of this. Is there any way go around this?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with expected input and output

Comment: Try like $("#main").attr("class", "mainWide");